# omp + valgrind resulting in unexpected "possibly lost bytes"

Tags: c++, valgrind, openmp

```
int main() {
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i = i + 1) {
    std::cout << "some";
  }
  //other code
}
```

Valgrind report:

```
possibly lost: 2,128 bytes in 7 blocks
```

If I omit the "other code" in the example above everything works fine. Unfortunately I can not share the code. Is there maybe a common pattern for why this can happen? **Note that in the "other code" no parallelism is involved.**

Nb: I also tried something else in the loop than `cout` and it was the same issue.

EDIT: Maybe it goes without saying but to make sure: Dropping `#pragma omp parallel for` results in a report without any leaks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738938/valgrind-legitimate-possibly-lost-bytes-example

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this issue? I'm still experiencing it today

Comment: @p4t Unfortunately I don't remember. It has been too long.

Comment: All good. Thanks for getting back to me anyways.