# Finding the "random pointer" with valgrind "possibly lost"

Tags: c++, valgrind

Valgrind is complaining of bytes being *possibly lost* in one part of our large C++ program.  After reading [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738938/valgrind-legitimate-possibly-lost-bytes-example) and [the manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html) on "possibly lost" I think I understand what the error is about, but I don't understand the error in this specific case.

`mpConsDbKey` is not modified anywhere in the class (or derived classes), so the pointer is not being advanced or reassigned.  The valgrind manual says "possibly lost" could also be declared if a "random value in memory points into the block"

Is there any way to know, via Valgrind, **why** it thinks it is lost?

If it is a random block of memory, best to not waste time looking for it...

**Valgrind Manual**

> "Possibly lost". This covers cases 5--8 (for the BBB blocks) above.
>   This means that a chain of one or more pointers to the block has been
>   found, but at least one of the pointers is an interior-pointer. This
>   could just be a random value in memory that happens to point into a
>   block, and so you shouldn't consider this ok unless you know you have
>   interior-pointers.

**Source Code & Error**

```
DvDaTestBC::DvDaTestBC()
{
    mpConsDbKey = new DvDbConsolidator; // <<== error here
}


DvDaTestBC::~DvDaTestBC()
{
    delete mpConsDbKey;
}
```

Type Hierarchy:

[image]

Error Text:

```
==2745== 88 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5,750 of 8,333
==2745==    at 0x4007D47: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:292)
==2745==    by 0x50B5ED8: DvDaTestBC::DvDaTestBC(unsigned long, unsigned short, unsigned long, std::string const&, short) (DvDaTestBC.cpp:68)
==2745==    by 0x50BCCCE: DvDaTest::DvDaTest(unsigned long, unsigned short, unsigned long, std::string const&, DvDbAlarmConfigSet const&, Dv::ETestState, short) (DvDaTest.cpp:23)
==2745==    by 0x52157F1: DvDaMipErrorReporter::createTests() (DvDaMipErrorReporter.cpp:177)
==2745==    by 0x521427F: DvDaMipErrorReporter::DvDaMipErrorReporter(unsigned short, unsigned short) (DvDaMipErrorReporter.cpp:65)
==2745==    by 0x554DE25: DvCfgTspModuleMgrBC::createDAs() (DvCfgTspModuleMgrBC.cpp:742)
```

Comment: Probably `DvDaTestBC` is part of some inheritance hierarchy lacking [virtual destructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203).

Comment: You should check whether the destructor is actually being called by printing a message to the terminal or so.

Comment: That's a good hint.  Question: do classes both above AND below `DvDaTestBC` need virtual destructors?  Or just `DvDaTestBC` and above?
 (Not all classes in the hierarchy have virtual methods).  See type hierarchy above

Comment: @Danny It depends how the `DvDaTestBC` object is being destroyed. If it's being deleted via a pointer to a base type, that base type (or an ancestor of that base type) needs a virtual destructor. Also, make sure `DvDaTestBC` obeys the rule of three/five.